# Why is ggradar polygon fill colour different to polygon colour?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggradar

I have a dataframe, sampdf, which looks like this:

| name | cat1 | cat2 | cat3 | cat4 | cat5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Any Name | 0.6198695 | 0.8864993 | 0.6239897 | 0.9735296 | 0.9735149 |

I wish to plot this as a (filled) polygon using ggradar.

Here's my code:

```
ggradar(sampdf, 
        group.colours = "slateblue4", 
        fill="TRUE", 
        group.point.size = 2, 
        font.radar = "NeueHaasDisplay-Roman", 
        axis.label.size = 6) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

Here's the resulting chart:

[image: radar chart for sampdf]

Why is the fill colour red rather than slateblue4? Apologies if there is something simple I'm missing but this is driving me crazy!

Tried the code above, expecting the fill colour to be slateblue4, in fact it was red

Answer (score 1):

Your code is *almost* correct, you just need to unquote `TRUE` in the `fill` argument e.g. :

```r
sampdf <- tibble::tribble(
  ~name,    ~cat1,  ~cat2,  ~cat3,  ~cat4,  ~cat5,
  "Any Name",   0.6198695,  0.8864993,  0.6239897,  0.9735296,  0.9735149
)

ggradar(sampdf, 
        group.colours = "slateblue4", 
        fill=TRUE, 
        group.point.size = 2, 
        font.radar = "NeueHaasDisplay-Roman", 
        axis.label.size = 6) +
theme_void() +
theme(legend.position = "none")
```

which gives:

[image: Radar chart with blue fill colour]